# How to broadcast a numpy 2D-array to a 6D-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcast

I have three six-dimensional **`Numpy`** arrays (running on python 3.4) of form

```
Weights 
MyValue 
WeightedValue  = Weight * MyValue
```

I would like to determine the weighted average of `MyValue` weighted by `Weights`' axis-`j` (which may range from 0 to 4) across the other axes, except axis `5` is constant.

( So when `j=2`, we are averaging across `0,1,3,` and `4` ).

I then intend to  take this average and multiply by `Weights` and subtract the product from `WeightedValue`

I intend to do this is

```
NewArray   = WeightedValue - Weight * fn( Weighted Value, Weights )
NewMyValue = NewArray / Weights
```

the **`fn()`** would be the average  of `MyValue` defined as:

```
               the sum of Weighted Value using 4 axes ( all except j and 5 )
< divided by >---------------------------------------------------------------
               the sum of Weights across 4 axes       ( all except j and 5 )
```

**My problem is as follows:**

Average Value is a 2D-array, I need the `fn()` to generate a 6D-array, i.e. to **broadcast** the 2D-result over the other 4-dimensions

I could as a last resort create a series of loops to iterate over axes `j` and axis `5`.For the second axis(j=1) the loop would be as follows

```
import numpy as np
result = np.zeros((dim0,dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4,dim5))
for var1 in range(dim1):
    for var5 in range(dim5):
        result[:,dim1,:,:,:,dim5] = AverageValue[dim1,dim5]
```

But I am hoping there is a more straightforward and general way

Comment: Consider adding example code that runs stand-alone. If you know how to do this with loops, use them and we can help you remove them. Check out ['how to ask a good question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A small example that we can run, as well as your desired output from that example, can be very helpful. That way, potential answerers know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of `fn` you could use:

```
j = 1;
axes = tuple({0,1,2,3,4} - {j})
fn = WeightedValue.sum(axes, keepdims=True) / Weights.sum(axes, keepdims=True)
```

The key thing obviously is to pass `keepdims=True`, which keeps singleton dimensions in the result for the summation axes and makes the result suitable for further broadcasting.